# Managing number of test cases in ALM

Tags: automated-testing, testcase, hp-alm

I'm using ALM to create test cases to cover different customer creation workflows.

The challenge is that when you look up a customer, there are at least 20 ways to do so (through name search, CVR, birth date, etc.).

Question: I would like to minimize the number of test cases I need to create in ALM, while still covering all the options to look up a customer. Is there a way to do so?
Can I create one test case, and test multiple lookup options within the same case?

Answer (score 1):

Since throughly testing would be unfeasible, have two options:

- Do a risk analysis and perform only a subset of the possible tests, trying to cover all ways in a limited number of ways.
- Do random testing. You would have to model the creation flow, so you could generate a random state and check if the output matches the model.

In both cases, you should sync with the developers to perform more throughly testing in the unit/integration level, given your E2E testing is limited.

Comment: Why is thoroughly testing infeasible?

Comment: There is the "combinatorial explosion of test cases" problem. Consider you have a system with n test cases, running on Windows. If you come to support Linux, you'll have 2 * n test cases. If you come to support m number of OS`s, you'll have m * n test cases. If you support t number of browsers, you'll have t * m * n test cases. Any non-trivial system has combinatorial tests cases. James Bach wrote about a popular technique to deal with it called "pairwise testing". http://www.testingeducation.org/wtst5/PairwisePNSQC2004.pdf. There are approaches with AI as well nowadays.

Comment: I understand. But in a limited domain (like the one posed by the OP), thoroughly testing is certainly feasible. And in this case, it may even be necessary.

Comment: "The challenge is that when you look up a customer, there are at least 20 ways to do so (through name search, CVR, birth date, etc.).". At least 20! teste cases. If you consider the a name input could be of many types (empty, ASCII, unicode, big, too big, "God, that's big") you will have even more tests.
Test case explosion happens in any non-trivial system. The one described is not trivial (nor complex).

Comment: 20 test cases doesn't seem infeasible to me. And throwing varied data at it is rather trivial for automation. It's something many of us do every day.

Comment: 20! == 20 * 19 * 18 ... * 2 * 1

Comment: Factorials don't apply here. If there are 20 ways to log in, you don't need to perform each of them in a different order.

Comment: We are talking about 20 different fields, not 20 (excludent) ways of doing something. It's like walking through a full-connected graph. You would have factorial explosion.

Comment: Sorry, I think you are mistaken. "20 ways to do so" does not mean 20 fields. It's basically 20 paths - each of which has no relationship with the other. I understand the combinatorics of interconnected fields, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

What you want for this, assuming you have intelligent testers who aren't expected to follow a "click this button" script, is to define one test case for customer lookup, and in that test case, list the ways to search for a customer.

Depending on how your system works, you should be able to define the search methods as test parameters that can be used in customer search - especially if you keep your description at a high level.

For example:

"Given that Customer X has a %PARAMETER% stored in the system, when I search for customers by %PARAMETER%, I should see the Customer X in the list of matching customers."

Parameters could be:

- Full name
- Contact name
- Zip code
- Birth date
- date of last purchase

Pretty much any of the fields that you could search on.

Note that you should also include test cases for customers who have nothing stored in the field e.g. customers with no birth date stored should never be returned when searching by date of birth; and for customers who have a different value than the search value e.g a customer who does not have zip code 12345 should not appear in the search results for zip code 12345.